# nodejs not returning external api call to originator caller

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

The app structure is angularjs (client), nodejs (server), service layer (external api). The call chain is successful as I get the value expected back in the nodejs layer but it never makes it back to the originating call in angularjs. I believe I need to pass a callback function from angular but my attempts have failed so I'll provide the original code I started with.

[Updated] originating call from angularjs layer. the findCustomers function is bound to the typeahead component of ui-bootstrap directive:

```
  $scope.findCustomers = function(chars) {
    var customers = [],
        url = 'api/v1/accounts/' + encodeURIComponent(chars) + '/';

    try
    {
        //return $http.jsonp(url)
        return $http.get(url)
            .then(function(res) {
                if(res.data)
                {
                    customers = angular.fromJson(res.data);
                }

                return customers;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log('Unable to load the customers: ' + JSON.stringify(error))
            });
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("error searching comapny: " + e);
    }

  }
```

nodejs route set up to handle the call:

```
  app.use('/api/v1/accounts/:search', stormpath.loginRequired, apiAccounts.findAll);
```

actual route. When I inspect the body I can see the expected result. I tired adding a next() and returning the payload (amongst many other things) but nothing worked.

```
  var http = require('http');

  var accounts = {
      findAll: function(req, res) {
        var callUrl, customers = [],
        urls = {
            apiBaseUrl: config.baseUrl,
            companyApi: '/api/office/companynames/'
        },
        searchValue = req.params.search;

         //console.log('in api accounts.findAll: ' + searchValue);

        return http.get({
                    host: urls.apiBaseUrl,
                    path: urls.companyApi + searchValue + '/'
               }, function(response) {
               var body = '';
               response.on('data', function(d) {
                  body += d;
               });
               response.on('end', function() {
                  //console.log('... in response.end');
                  customers = body;

                  res.json(customers);

                  //return JSON.stringify(customers);
             });
          });
        }
      };

      module.exports = accounts;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach `customers` to the scope. You are getting confused with async, promises, and sync function return values. Instead of `return customers;` in your controller, just make sure `$scope.customers` is assigned to the correct array and angular will take it from there.

Comment: Thank you @Peter-Lyons, you helped me take a fresh look at it. It ended up being a mixture of items, one being the external api config and then I needed to convert the respnse back to a javascript array for ui-bootstrap to work

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter Lyons, I took a step back and stepped through the code with a fresh pair of eyes. There were a few tweaks on the external api side that helped but that wasn't the culprit. The issue was the format of the response. The typeahead ui-bootstrap component was expecting an array of objects versus the format being returned, a string. the fix:

```
  customers = angular.fromJson(res.data);
```